# wordpress blogs in different pages

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, categories

I have a page containing a set of images linked to other pages. How can I make each of the linked pages a separate blog?

[image]

To give you some more context, each image represents a challenge that I set myself up to and I would like to have a separate 'blog' for each challenge to document my progress. So far I have managed to link pages together and navigate from the page containing all the challenges to the page containing the details about 1 single challenge. However the latter page is not a blog so I cannot add new posts to the page. If I try to write a new blog post it gets added above the challenges(list) page

[This](https://the-challenge-club.com/challenges/) is a link to the page that I am refering to.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use categories for your posts - like Challenge One and Challenge Two - and then your posts will be automatically organized into category archives. Add a third category - called All Challenges - to all the posts and that category archive will list all posts in all three categories by chronology.

The URLs to the category archive pages will be something like this, depending on your category names and slugs, and how you set up your category base in Settings>>Permalinks.

> example.com/categories/challenge-one
>
> example.com/categories/challenge-two
>
> example.com/categories/all-challenges

Link those category archive URLs from your images on your main page that has a gallery of images for each challenge post category.

You can make up custom category templates for each category, so the layout and design can be different.

See

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Category_base_and_Tag_base

and

https://make.wordpress.org/training/handbook/user-lessons/categories-vs-tags/

and

https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this in WordPress. Let me tell you the easiest one:-

**Using Post Categories**

Follow the steps below:

Step1: Break your challenges into different categories, for example Challenge 1, Challenge 2, and so on... You can easily do that by creating and choosing the right category while writing a post.

Step2: Go Settings->Premalinks in your WordPress dashboard and choose "Post Name".

Step3: Now you have to find the new links for your challenge images. You can find these links in Post->Categories tab within your dashboard. Once you are in the categories browse page within your WordPress dashboard, just hover over the category whose link you want and you will see a "View" tab which will take you to that particular category page. This category page will show only the posts that you have published under that particular category.

Step4: Once you have the category link with you just update it in the respective challenge image link.

I hope you will be able to resolve your issue with this.